# How to map json payload to model bean in struts2

Tags: struts2

Is there any way to map json payload to Model bean.? If possible, please provide me an example.

Following are the classes I am using.

```
package com.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int id;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Employee [firstName=").append(firstName)
                .append(", lastName=").append(lastName).append(", id=")
                .append(id).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Following is my action class.

```
package com.sample.controller;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
    import com.sample.Employee;

    public class EmployeeController implements ModelDriven<Employee> {
        private String name = "Hari krishna";
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        public String addEmployee() {
            System.out.println(emp);
            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        public Employee getModel() {
            return emp;
        }
    }
```

Following is my struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="jsonStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="json">
                    <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="addEmployee" class = "com.sample.controller.EmployeeController" method = "addEmployee">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

When I call the action "addEmployee", with json data "{"firstName":"Hari","id":123,"lastName":"assds"}" I am getting following response. I set content type to text/json.

```
{
"model": {
"firstName": null
"id": 0
"lastName": null
}-
}
```

I am posting data using Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: I tried to integrate Jersey but didn't work. I didn't find much examples related to struts2-json plugin related to post request.

Comment: I followed the answer given in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824833/how-to-post-an-array-of-object-in-json-to-struts2-action"

Comment: Model class Employee initialzed with null values like "Employee [firstName=null, lastName=null, id=0]". but, I am passing json {"firstName":"Hari","id":123,"lastName":"assds"} to my action url.

Comment: I posted my configuration. Can you pls tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: You are configuring only one interceptor for the action. Use `defaultStack` and add json interceptor to it.

Comment: Thnx Aleksandr. It works

Answer (score -1):

when you send the json data from client to server, send them as string and in action class create a normal String variable to receive and hold the json's string.

Then, you can manually populate your bean from string using json parser, 
or use a lib like [google gson](https://github.com/google/gson) that has a build in features for this purposes.

Google Gson is a Java serialization/deserialization library that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back.

You can create your own struts Interceptor to wrap this process or implements it directly inside your action class.

Comment: Not useful. There is s2-json plugin for that.

Comment: It was useful a lot to me , so I shared my opinion. AND if there is a s2-json plugin that does not mean you can not create your OWN SIMPLE suitable  solution.